# Common node structure for binary search tree and AVL tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I want to define a common node structure for binary search tree (BST) and AVL tree. To achieve this, I have defined the following structure in CommonNode.h file.

```
struct CommonNode{
int data;
struct CommonNode *left, *right;
};
typedef struct CommonNode node;
```

In another file BST.h, I have defined a structure for BST node

```
struct bsTree{
node *nodePtr;
};
typedef struct bsTree bst;
```

In another file AVL.h, I have defined a structure for AVL node

```
struct AVLTree{
node *nodePtr;
int balanceFactor;
};
typedef struct AVLTree avl;
```

Consider the following code (code to search for `value` in the tree)

```
avl *p;
p = root; // assume that pointer to root is given
while(p!=NULL){
    if(value < p->nodePtr->data)  // value
        p = p->nodePtr->left;
    else
        p = p->nodePtr->right;
}
```

This method is not correct because `p->nodePtr->left;` points to structure `CommonNode` and `p` is the pointer to structure `AVLTree`.
My question is, what is the correct way of defining common node structure for this problem ?.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree and from there http://piumarta.com/software/tree/

Comment: On a 64-bit system, there'll be 32-bits of padding in the `struct CommonNode`.  You might as well add the `balanceFactor` into that structure and save yourself all the angst.  On a 32-bit system, that would mean that common nodes use 32-bits more in a BST than is minimally necessary.  You'll have to judge whether that's an issue for you — but going with a single structure would be simpler.  Also, both `struct AVLTree` and `struct bsTree` would do better holding a `struct CommonNode` directly, rather than a pointer to a `struct CommonNode` — that's a completely unnecessary level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

This might be Helpful for You

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct CommonNode{
int data;
struct CommonNode *left, *right;
};

typedef struct CommonNode node;

struct bsTree{
node *nodePtr;
};

typedef struct bsTree bst;

struct AVLTree{
node *nodePtr;
int balanceFactor;
};

typedef struct AVLTree avl;


int main()
{
avl *p;
p = (struct AVLTree*)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLTree));
p->nodePtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
p->nodePtr->data = 20;
printf("The data value is %d\n",p->nodePtr->data);
return 0;
}


OUTPUT:
The data value is 20
```

Comment: Problem is not with accessing the data, but with pointer type.  `p->nodePtr->left` points to `node`, but I want it to point to `struct AVLTree`

Comment: @Hegde what you have done is correct. you have put a common thing in one structure and then you are using it to both BST and AVL. according to you its something like nested structure. the p->nodePtr->left is pointing to AVL only. it is something like within AVL you have CommonNode structure.